# Constructing an address book with Bash - editing the fields with sed produces the wrong result

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I want to use Bash to make an address book but I'm having problems editing fields.

The fields are `name;number;mail`.

This is my code. I want to edit for example the name, or the name and the number, only at the line where mail (`correo`) match. Thank you all.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hola "$USER". Este es un script para guardar y actualizar su agenda."
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
if test ! -f agenda.sh
then
    touch agenda.sh
    chmod 770 agenda.sh
    echo "No tenías una agenda, la creé para ti"
fi
agenda="agenda.sh"
nombre=$1
numero=$2
correo=$3

grep -i "$correo" "$agenda"

if [ $? == 0 ] 
then
    echo "Ya esta registrado con esto correo("$correo")" 
    nom=`grep $correo $agenda | cut -f1 -d ";"`
    telefono=`grep $correo $agenda | cut -f2 -d ";"`
    echo "Datos vecho: $nom $telefono"
    echo "Datos nuevo: $1 $2"
    echo "Quieres sobrescribir los datos?(y/n): "
    read respuesta
    if test $respuesta == "n"
    then
        exit 1
    elif test $respuesta == "y"
    then
         sed -e "s/$nom/$1/g" -e "s/$telefono/$2/g" $agenda >/tmp/salida && mv /tmp/salida $agenda
         echo "Datos sobrescritos"
         sort -k 2 -t";" $agenda
    fi
else
    echo "$nombre;$numero;$correo" >> "$agenda" 
    echo "Se ha añadido a la agenda."
    sort -k 2 -t";" $agenda
fi
```

[image: OUTPUT]

This is the output, but there is an error. If for example in my address book I have:

```
sergio;damico;sergiodamico@gmail.com
```

and I replace with

```
marco rossi
```

I want to have

```
marco;rossi;sergiodamico@gmail.com
```

and not

```
marco;rossi;marcorossi@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to fix this by changing your sed line:

**Option 1** (recommended):
Match on `$name$delimiter` instead of just `$name`. Your delimiter is `';'` so add it to the match and replace strings:

```
sed -e "s/${nom};/${1};/g"
```

**Option 2** (not recommended on it's own):
`/g` says match *all* instances of `${nom}` on a line - when you only want to match the first - remove the g:

```
sed -e "s/${nom}/${1}/"
```

**Option 3** (use both to be more accurate):

```
sed -e "s/${nom};/${1};/"
```

Lastly, you are creating temporary files and moving them because you are using `sed -e`. You can use sed to edit the file directly, using `sed -i` then you don't have to worry about creating temp files and moving them over the originals